# Write into a python slice?

Tags: python

Attempting to simply write into an existing (already filled) slice in python.

```
data = list([0] * 80)
bytes = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
print len(data) # 80
data[0:] = bytes
print (len(data)) # 5
```

What I really wanted was to only modify the first 5 integers and leave the rest of the data list as zeros.  However, what I did was shrink my list.

What is the right way to copy my bytes into data without shrinking it?

Comment: You may want to use `data=bytearray(80)` instead of the list, since it looks like you are using character data

Answer (score 3):

```
data = list([0] * 80)
bytes = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
data[:5] = bytes
```

The slice `data[0:]` represents the entire array, so the entire array will be replaced with what you provide. If you only want to replace a specific slice, you should specify it. Here, I've specified the slice `data[:5]`, which is the first 5 elements of `data`. If you needed it to be dynamic, you could substitute `len(bytes)` for `5`.

Comment: Thanks, thought there would be a more general purpose answer but good enough.  Curious why python shrinks or grows the list, you would think there would be some other syntax to constrain the assignment to the slice boundaries.  Now I have to check it myself.

Comment: Python does constrain the assignment to the slice boundaries.  The slice [:5] means "from the beginning (item 0) to item 5, non-inclusive" which is the same as "from item 0 to item 4 inclusive" or the first five items.

Comment: You could also do the above this way: `data[:len(bytes)] = bytes`  That would explicitly check the length of `bytes` and replace the first items in data with items from `bytes`.

Comment: You can also write your own list subclass that does slice assignments based on the length of the sequence being assigned. (This may be trickier than you think, though -- watch out for generators!)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to slices:

```
data = list([0] * 80)
bytes = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
data[:5] = bytes # data[:5] is a slice
print data # [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 0, ... ]
```

What you did with `data[0:] = bytes` (or `data[:]`) is to overwrite the whole list with the elements from `bytes`.

Comment: Sure I know, the intent was to write "within" the bounds of the slice without having to do the bounds checking myself.  Otherwise, python shrinks or grows my data list.

Comment: There is no such thing as "within a slice" unless you re-slice or re-index it. Assignment replaces the slice. There is no reason why the replacement should have to have the same number of elements. The list is not an array, it's a list.

Comment: @Karl, but the underlying datastructure in CPython is an array

Comment: @gnibbler Doesn't matter. The interface is what it is.